# How to query a large DbSet with AsNoTracking and a CancellationToken

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, cancellation-token

I know a lot of work was done in EF6 to support async operations such as CountAsync, but I can't seem to cancel a simple query.  Here's the story.

I have a query that returns 4.5 million rows.  I need to process each row, but I can't hold all of them in memory.  EF6 is kind enough to let me do this:

```
foreach (var row in context.TableX.AsNoTracking())
{
...process each row
}
```

This works great and uses very little memory, but it's not very easy to cancel.  I tried this silliness:

```
foreach (var row in context.TableX.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(token).Result)
{
...process each row
}
```

Of course, this tries to loads the entire query into a List<> which crashes long before all the rows are loaded.  Thankfully, it is very responsive to a cancellation.  :)

The closest I've gotten is to wrap the whole mess like this:

```
Task.Run(() => DoQuery(), token);
```

This doesn't chew up memory and I *can* cancel it, but the cancellation takes forever to respond and there's some nasty exceptions because I'm pulling the rug out.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When do you want to be able to cancel - before even first row is received or during processing?

Comment: @Evk - Both.  This is operating inside a service and the cancel request could come in at any time.

Comment: "takes forever" because it does not actually cancel anything. Once the task has started running there is no way to call it off. .NET does not have non-cooperative cancellation.

Comment: Maybe you should request cancellation with lazy enumeration as an EF feature (on GitHub) assuming that no answer turns up. Evk's answer should work but it's not as composable as a foreach loop. EF support would be better.

Comment: @usr how this potential feature should look like? As I understand, after first result has arrived - you can cancel any time even in simple foreach loop by just breaking\throwing exception on token. Or you mean some extension method to cancel query itself until first result arrives?

Comment: @usr - Evk is right. You can cancel after the first record arrives thus my "takes forever" comment.

Comment: It could look like `foreach (var row in context.TableX.AsNoTracking().WithCancellation(token))`. That preserves the pull model. `ForEachAsync` is push which is less composable. For example, you can't treat the results as an `IEnumerable` anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public async Task DoQuery(CancellationToken token) {
    await ctx.TableX.AsNoTracking().ForEachAsync(row =>
    {
         // process here
    }, token);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Works like a charm.  Handling all the various exceptions that this coughed up was problematic, but I think I got it.  I had to handle the usual OperationCancelledException, AggregateExceptions that contained OperationCancelledExceptions, InnerExceptions that were OperationCancelledExceptions, and (my favorite) DataExceptions tossed by my SQL database (Oracle).  Too much fun, eh?